# Регулировка громкости

Tags: javascript, actionscript

Всем здравствуйте. У меня проблема. Я начал делать радио плеер и за основу взял flash. У меня к Вам вопрос: кто знает, можно ли написать javascript, который будет регулировать громкость в этом flash ролике. То есть когда меняешь громкость в ползунке, который написан на html, то громкость менялась бы и во flash ролике. Листание станций реализовал без проблем, а вот с громкостью проблема. Кто знает, как напишите или хотя бы посоветуйте, как можно реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно смотреть вот в [эту](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/bridge-to-flash) сторону.